# SPL token image not showing in Phantom wallet

Tags: spl-token, phantom

Does anyone uploaded metadata for a SPL token on the mainnet (https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com) recently ?

I uploaded the metadata, hosted on arweave both image and metadata json, but only the text and symbol changed, the image is still the question mark. Does it takes time to populate ?

Note: logo is showing properly on [solscan](https://solscan.io/token/8AxFH7RYhBHMVHdhKXKEQJpedv5S41BofwVb2oJ1LNxf#metadata) and it works good with devnet

Thanks

[image]

---

**UPDATE :** I contacted support, it can take up to a week so let's wait a little bit. Thanks Phantom support for quick answer!

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the token on chain?

Comment: Yep, I just updated the post, here's the solscan link : https://solscan.io/token/8AxFH7RYhBHMVHdhKXKEQJpedv5S41BofwVb2oJ1LNxf#metadata, thanks

Comment: Thanks, can you also post the Token minted on devnet?

Comment: here's the devnet token https://solscan.io/token/9L2y2aYnSXWnUrj1ThttJ9i3SgT7JryN4QDswiqmbVeM?cluster=devnet#holders, doesnt show in solscan but shows properly in phantom wallet ---_---   Using the same method to upload metadata

Comment: Nice, it looks like the image is showing up properly for me on Solscan (mainnet). It looks like you did everything properly -- for posterity: 

Use createMetadataV2 instruction to assign the token metadata according to the Metaplex Token Standard
https://github.com/solana-labs/token-list
  ---
Did you try anything new recently that may explain why it's appearing now but didn't 15 minutes ago? Maybe it just needs some time to pull the image.

Comment: Didn't change anything the last 10 hours :( .. Here's what Phantom wallet shows : https://i.ibb.co/YyQ1p3N/Screen-Shot-2022-08-09-at-6-12-20-AM.png
I'm gonna wait a little bit more and then try to update again, maybe with an other image link and not arweave ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the logo and metadata are showing correctly on SolScan, it *should* be rendering in Phantom as well.

You can clear the cache directly for Phantom by:

- Open phantom
- Right-click and inspect
- Go to the `Application` tab on the DevTools window that comes up
- Select `Storage` in the left menu
- Hit the `Clear site data` button

[image]

Comment: good but you forgot to say you have to select `storage` from the left list, before you can find `clear site data` button.

Answer (score 1):

The old method of commiting a token to solana/token-list got deprecated end of june. At the moment the correct and proper way to create SPL token with metadata, is by running `createCreateMetadataAccountV2Instruction` from `@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata` library. No, it doesn't take an hour, a day or a week for any cache in phantom to refresh, it's instant. I've just created it with a method above and it shows instantly on solscan, and phantom:
[image][image]